# Python GTK4: CheckButton 'toggled' signal called dozens of times

Tags: python, gtk, gnome

Running a Python program that I wanted to add a GTK Settings menu to. The below functions as needed, but there's a couple problems with it. Here's the relevant code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def gtk_on_activate(app):
    win = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(application=app)
    win.set_title('Settings')
    win.set_default_size(320,240)
    box = Gtk.ListBox()
    for k,v in config['Settings'].items():
        btn = Gtk.CheckButton(label=k,active=bool(int(v)))
        btn.connect('toggled', gtk_toggled)
        box.append(btn)
    win.set_child(box)
    win.present()   

def gtk_toggled(btn):
    global config
    print('hi')
    btn.set_active(not btn.get_active())
    config.set('Subscriptions', btn.get_label(), str(int(btn.get_active())))
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Config/SavedVariables.cfg'), 'w') as cfg:
        config.write(cfg)

app = Gtk.Application(application_id='org.gdi.Settings')
app.connect('activate', gtk_on_activate)
app.run()
```

And here's the output:

```
[...]
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
Traceback (most recent call last):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xyz/.local/bin/scripts/Settings/Settings.py", line 95, in gtk_toggled
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Config/SavedVariables.cfg'), 'w') as cfg:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

What I imagine the `RecursionError` is about is that file likely being opened dozens of times. But I don't understand:

1. Why that `print('hi')` is required for the code to even work(other strings work)?
2. Why is the signal being sent dozens and dozens of times?
3. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you for any and all help!

EDIT: I've since moved the `open` out of that function, and that solved the `RecursionError`. I also have now tried with Gtk3, and noticed the same pattern of the signal being spammed. So I guess it's just normal? Gtk3 seems to have solved the `print('hi')` being an odd requirement. I noticed with Gtk4, that weird trick only worked if the program was run from the terminal. Don't really understand what's going on there... Perhaps I should file a bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the code so that it works with Gtk 3 (and without error messages relating to `config`), and it seems to be that the problem comes down to the `btn.set_active(not btn.get_active())` line. Here is the code I used:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def gtk_on_activate(app):
    win = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(application=app)
    win.set_title('Settings')
    win.set_default_size(320,240)
    box = Gtk.ListBox()
    for k,v in {"Button1": "1", "Button2": "0", "Button3": "1"}.items():
        btn = Gtk.CheckButton(label=k,active=bool(int(v)))
        btn.connect('toggled', gtk_toggled)
        box.insert(btn, 0)
    win.add(box)
    win.show_all()
    win.present()   

def gtk_toggled(btn):
    print('hi')
    btn.set_active(not btn.get_active()) # This line is causing the error message

app = Gtk.Application(application_id='org.gdi.Settings')
app.connect('activate', gtk_on_activate)
app.run()
```

To fix this, just remove the `btn.set_active(not btn.get_active())`. It's completely useless, since the checkbutton will automatically change its state by itself. And if you don't want the user to be able to change the state of the checkbutton, just use `btn.set_sensitive(False)` for any checkbuttons you want to be disabled.

So, in answer to your questions:

1. `print('hi')` *isn't* required for the code to work; the code fails whether you `print('hi')` or not (at least in Gtk 3).
2. The signal is being sent so many times because the `btn.set_active()` function in the `btn.set_active(not btn.get_active())` line sends `toggled` signal, which then calls `gtk_toggled()`, which calls `btn.set_active()`, which sends the `toggled` signal, which calls `gtk_toggled()`, which then calls `btn.set_active()`, on and on and on until the maximum recursion depth is reached.
3. Yes, you are doing something wrong. Fortunately, it's just about the simplest and easiest error to fix, and the fix is actually *less* code and complication; you can let Gtk do the work for you!

And no, thankfully it's not normal, and no, you don't need to file a bug report.

Comment: Always the stupid mistakes. lol. Now that I think about that, I added that due to the weird Gtk4 error where I needed to add the `print('hi')`. In Gtk4, the problem was it wouldn't actually be set to active on click. I bet I added them at the same time, it started working, and I assumed it was the `btn.set_active()` that was doing it and completely forgot. lol

Comment: I've since, after testing it with Gtk3, set it back to Gtk4, and it's working as it should. I imagine the weird `print()` thing was a result of the recursion problem. I don't know. It sounds extremely weird, but I swear there actually was a problem where without the `print()`, it wouldn't function properly. lol

Comment: Glad to help! Again, I don't use Gtk 4 (yet), so I don't know whether the `print()` would affect it or not. It's unlikely, but there was enough other stuff potentially involved in causing the problem that you might have gotten it mixed up :-).